# Caching Panel page variants

Tags: panels, caching, chaos-tool-suite

I don't believe I have never run into this before, but I have a [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) page with a few variants based on selection rules.  Is there a way that you can serve up cached results for the whole page (not just the individual panes) after the selection rules have run?  I am not seeing any options or other modules to get Page Manager to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try any off the following module

[Panels Page Cache](http://drupal.org/project/panels_page_cache)

> This plugin can cache panels based on the path/url (arg() structure).
>
> This is needed if a panel has content which is dynamically per page
>   (eg ad-tags, content related items).

[Panels Hash Cache](http://drupal.org/project/panels_hash_cache)

> This module provides a hash-based cache for Panels and other Chaos
>   Tools powered displays.
>   This support caching based on any combination of:
>
> ```
> Contexts (node, term, user etc)
> Arguments
> Drupal Path (args) (same as the Panels Page Cache Module)
> Full URL (including domain and query string)
> Users
> Roles
> ```

Comment: I feel like an idiot; I'm accepting this because it led me down the right path.  I played with both of those modules for a while today before I posted this question.  Variant level caching is under **Display Settings** on the **Content** tab.  Caching is built-in, and these two modules provide other options.

Comment: One more option is the [ESI module](http://drupal.org/project/esi)