# Where do i enable caching for drupal 7 panels data for Logged in Authenticated users?

Tags: 7, panels, caching

For drupal 7 panels where do i set the settings to enable caching for logged in authenticated users?

Comment: Where did you get the idea there is a separate cache for that? (I really wanna know - the same documentation should tell / point to place that tells how.)

Comment: what i meant was for the panels module. was wondering if there was a separate section just to enable cache for panels content or is it just in the same general cache page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable Panels caching on a per-panel-pane basis.

Edit the panel pane and set the "Cache" configuration there.

[image: Panel pane cache settings]

You can also create your own cache plugins via the ctools plugin API.

Comment: There are also a few contrib modules that add new cache strategies for Panels

Comment: where would i find these cache modules for panels?

Comment: A few panels caching modules are mentioned here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/47984/11788